# Count function - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I have these practice tables to work with:

```
create table complaints (compid int, compdate date, fineid int, description varchar)
insert into complaints values
(1010, '24-FEB-2017', 10001, NULL),
(1011, '01-AUG-2017', 10003, NULL),
(1012, '30-JUL-2017', 10004, NULL),
(1013, '02-MAR-2017', 10001, NULL)

create table Fines (fineID int, finedate date, empid int, amount int)
insert into Fines values
(10001, '01-FEB-2017', 1, 250),
(10002, '11-MAR-2017', 2, 250),
(10003, '25-JUN-2017', 4, 500),
(10004, '23-JUL-2017', 4, 250)
(10005, '31-JUL-2017', 3, 250)

create table Employees (empid int, empname nvarchar(100), workingsince date)
insert into Employees values
(1,'John','01-JAN-2007'),
(2,'Abe','01-JUL-2008'),
(3,'Don','01-JAN-2013'),
(4,'Gon','01-JAN-2017')
```

Now, I want to create a query that will show me for each employee name, the number of fines and the number of complaints (all in the same table - empname, NumofFines, NumOfComp).

It seems I need 2 columns with the count function and I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: What are the primary keys of all tables involved? Also the data model seems wrong. An employee can have zero to many fines. And each fine can have  zero to many complaints but there may be a fine with out any corresponding complaint? So what is the fine for?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Employee can give 0 to many fines, each fine can have 0 to many compliants. And yes, there can be a fine which was given by employee and has no complaints. Or maybe I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Right - I understand. I though the fines were being received by employees in response to complaints. I now  see that they are being issued by employees and may result in a complaint

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
select 
    e.empname,
    count(distinct f.fineid) no_fines,
    count(distinct c.compid) no_complaints
from employees e
left join fines f      on f.empid = e.empid
left join complaints c on c.fineid = f.fineid
group by e.empid, e.empname
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=adaca34100f5a6964191acc74fd070b1)**:

```
empname | no_fines | no_complaints
:------ | -------: | ------------:
Abe     |        1 |             0
Don     |        1 |             0
Gon     |        2 |             2
John    |        1 |             2
```

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida: that's in case there is more than one fine for a given complaint.

Comment: Doesn't seem like that should be possible. Presumably `compid` is PK of `complaints` - so each complaint is associated with exactly one fine per the `fineid` column